# Twitter Streaming API Application - Where To Host?

Tags: python, hosting, daemon

I've written a python script that connects to the Twitter Streaming API. This is a consistent connection that I needs to kept alive as it feeds data into my overall application. Currently this is running on my own machine on Ubuntu; however I'm trying to find a service online that can host my file and run the script continuously. I've heard of using Daemons to do this?

Is there a service out there that can do what I'm looking for?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask this over on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Super User](http://www.superuser.com), as it might not be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

I used a remote desktop connection with [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for a python script that stored Reddit comments. Back when I had it storing 200-500 comments every 3-4 minutes 24/7 it cost me about $0.50 a month (it's $0.001 for every IO past 1,000,000 IOs or something like that).

It's free for up to a year and you get 30 GB of hard drive storage. You can only use certain types of server OSs for free, though.

I believe you can use [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) for this as well but I don't know what their pricing is like.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I'll be sure to check those out, and also give this an ask on Server Fault and Super User.  Appreciate the response!